# cte using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I try to run the below query

```
  seq = row_number() over 
(
  partition by t.CustID
  order by t.InvoiceID, 
           t.Date,
           CASE WHEN t.S_Type = 'Receipt Voucher' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
 )

;

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT  CustID,
        [InvoiceID],
        S_Type,
        DATE,
        Debit,
        Credit,
        seq = row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CustID,
            ORDER BY InvoiceID,
                DATE,
                CASE 
                    WHEN S_Type = 'Receipt Voucher'
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 2
                    END
            )
    FROM Statement
    )
SELECT c.[InvoiceID],
    c.S_Type AS Type,
    c.DATE,
    .Debit,
    c.Credit,
    b.Balance
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
    FROM cte AS x
    WHERE x.CustID = c.CustID
        AND x.seq <= c.seq
    ) b
WHERE c.CustID = '48'
    AND DATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01'
        AND '2016-01-01'
ORDER BY seq
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 156,
>   Level 15, State 1, Line 21 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Remove the comma after `PARTITION BY CustId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here in your `Cte`:

```
...
seq = row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CustID,
        ORDER BY InvoiceID,
            DATE,
            CASE 
                WHEN S_Type = 'Receipt Voucher'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                END
        )
...
```

You have a `,` after `PARTITION BY CustID`, the correct syntax is without that comma:

```
...
seq = row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CustID
        ORDER BY InvoiceID,
            DATE,
            CASE 
                WHEN S_Type = 'Receipt Voucher'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                END
        )
...
```

Another issue you have in your query is that you do not have an alias for the `Debit` field in the final `SELECT`:

```
SELECT c.[InvoiceID],
    c.S_Type AS Type,
    c.DATE,
    .Debit,  <-- Here
    c.Credit,
    b.Balance
```

The full query would be as follows:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  CustId, InvoiceId, S_Type, Date, Debit, Credit,
            Seq = Row_Number() Over (   Partition By    CustId 
                                        Order By        InvoiceId, 
                                                        Date, 
                                                        Case 
                                                            When S_Type = 'Receipt Voucher' 
                                                                Then 1 
                                                            Else 2 
                                                        End
                                    )
    From    Statement
)
Select      C.InvoiceID,
            C.S_Type    As Type,
            C.Date,
            C.Debit,
            C.Credit,
            B.Balance
From        Cte     C
Cross Apply 
(
    Select  Balance = Sum(X.Debit) - Sum(X.Credit)
    From    Cte     X
    Where   X.CustId = C.CustId
    And     X.seq <= C.seq
) B
Where   C.CustID = '48'
And     C.Date Between '2015-01-01' And '2016-01-01'
Order By C.seq
```

Comment: still have errors incorrect syntax near PARTITION expecting '(' or select

Comment: I don't see anything else jumping out to me as being wrong in the query you provided...  Does your internal `CTE` query run on its own?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are not running the random script above your actual query (before the `WITH Cte`).  If you are running that, that may be part of your error.

Comment: i am not sure can you provide the full query may be i implemented wrongly

Comment: The only change I am proposing is the removal of the comma indicated in the answer.  The full query would be what you provided in the question from `WITH Cte` downwards.

Comment: still same issue and i didn't put coma after PARTITION BY CustId from the beging

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking at, but I copy/pasted the query from your question.  You most certainly have one there.